# Is this device Hamiltonian Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

I have a Hamiltonian with the form

$$\hat{H} = A(x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + B(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + C(x)$$

It can be found [here (see equation 7)](https://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0403/0403739.pdf). I want to use a finite-difference scheme (central difference), but it looks like my Hamiltonian will no longer be Hermitian. Specifically, if I expand the term $B(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ using a finite-difference scheme, I get matrix elements

$$h_{ij} = \delta_{i,j+1}B(i\Delta x)\frac{1}{\Delta x} - \delta_{i,j-1}B(i\Delta x)\frac{1}{\Delta x}$$

It looks like $h_{ij} = -h_{ji}$

If the middle term was not there, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That term is equal to $ip$ where $p$ is the momentum. To fix it, just multiply by $i$.

Comment: Can I simply multiply an individual term by $i$? According to the Hamiltonian in the above paper ( https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0403739 ), the function B(x) is real.

Comment: In case A, B, C depend of x the question about hermiticity is not reduced to multiplication by $i$.

Answer (score 2):

For this Hamiltonian been hermitian some conditions should be fulfilled:
$$
A^* = A
$$
$$
2A'^* - B^* = B
$$
$$
A''^* - B'^* + C^* = C
$$
Here $'$ means derivative and $^*$ means complex conjugate. In case when $A, B, C$ are actually independent of $x$, conditions are reduced to the $A$ and $C$ should be *real* and $B$ should be *imaginary*.